# javascript plugin questions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a newbie to JS, and I just have two questions to confirm for the following codes:

```
    // JavaScript Document

;(function($){
  $.fn.extend({
      //set a object-level plugin: border
      "border":function(options){
         //set options
         options=$.extend({
            width:"1px",
            line:"solid",
            color:"#090"
         },options);
         //set styles
       this.css("border",options.width+' '+options.line+' '+options.color);
       //to support chain grammar
       return this;       
      }
   });
})(jQuery)
```

the first question is why here we want to execute function($){}(jQuery) immediately? Does that mean the plugin starts before DOM is ready? and if we dont execute this function immediately, what will happen?

The second question is why options is extended using $.extend here? is that because we want to merge two objects?(options is object and {width:"1px", line:"solid",color:"#090"} is also object)

Best.

html code added:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>plugin example</title>
<style type="text/css">
   #test{
       font-size:9pt;      
       width:500px;
       height:50px;
   }
</style>
<!--jQuery library inclusion-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<!--jQuery plugin inclusion -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="CustomPlugin/jquery.border.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   //when the document is loaded，defining div's border
   $(document).ready(function(e) {
       //using border plugin
       $("#test").border({width:"5px","line":"dotted",color:"blue"}).css("background","green");
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="test">this example shows how to use plugin</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1: without showing how you *load* this plugin, we can't answer that. 2: we can't answer that either, because we don't know why you (or whoever is the author) wrote the code this way. All we can do is point you to https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/ and say "that's what it does, so that's what you (or whoever wrote this code) intended it to do."

Comment: hi, html file is added.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. You do not need the document to be ready before the snippet you posted gets executed. [`$.fn.extend()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/) adds a function to jQuery that you can *call* after DOM ready to add a border to an Element. But before you actually call `$.border`, the plugin needs to be registered to jQuery. In order to do this, jQuery has to finish loading before the Plugin, but not the DOM.

> and if we dont execute this function immediately, what will happen?

Nothing will go wrong unless `$.border` is called before the function is executed.
If you wrap both, the plugin and the function call in `$(document).ready` though, you cannot guarantee that the script loads first.

2. Yes. The options get merged with the default options in this case by using [`$.extend()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/). Please keep in mind that `$.extend` and `$.fn.extend` are two entirely different functions.

See:

```
    <div id="#myContainer">Hello World</div>

    <script src="./jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- jquery loaded and declares $ -->

    <script src="./jquery.borderPlugin.js"></script> 
    <!-- script is loaded and registers $.border() -->

    <script>
    // now you can use $.border()
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#myContainer').border({width:"5px"});
    }
    </script>
```

You only need the DOM to be ready, when you actually want to make changes to it. Since the Plugin just extends a variable and does not transform the DOM, it does not need to be executed in DOM Ready

Comment: thanks. as for the second question, is it possible to use the $.fn.extend method instead of $.extend method? and if so, how will the code change correspondingly?

Comment: no, $.fn.extend is for adding functions to jQuery and $.extend is for merging objects. These are completely different functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately invoked functions are used to ensure that certain values won't change throughout the lifetime of the code that is within the scope of this function. For jQuery plugins it is common practice to write:

```
(function($){
   // jQuery related code
})(jQuery)
```

This will ensure that all code inside of that function that uses `$` refers to the jQuery version that was passed to this function. You can see the difference in this code:

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    //set a object-level plugin: border
    "borderA": function(options) {
      //set options
      options = $.extend({
        width: "1px",
        line: "solid",
        color: "#090"
      }, options);
      //set styles
      this.css("border", options.width + ' ' + options.line + ' ' + options.color);
      //to support chain grammar
      return this;
    }
  });
})(jQuery)


 $.fn.extend({
   //set a object-level plugin: border
   "borderB": function(options) {
     //set options
     options = $.extend({
       width: "1px",
       line: "solid",
       color: "#090"
     }, options);
     //set styles
     this.css("border", options.width + ' ' + options.line + ' ' + options.color);
     //to support chain grammar
     return this;
   }
 });

 // some other code overwrites $
 $ = {}
 
 console.log('call borderA')
 jQuery('.test').borderA(); // works fine

 console.log('call borderB')
 jQuery('.test').borderB(); // fails because $ was overwritten
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Extending the functionality of jQuery using `$.fn.extend()` does not need any DOM elements, because it does not query anything.

`$.fn.extend()` extends the jQuery functions, `$.extend` merges two objects.

Comment: Thanks. I seem to understand what you mean. however, when I tried this code(not exactly the same, I put the definitions of the two plugins into a separate jquery.border.js file and include this js file into a html file ) but borderA could also not work properly. Is there anything wrong with my code?